# crear una expresiom regular C# para validar fechas

Tags: c#, regex, validación

¿Cómo elaboro una expresión regular en C# para validar una fecha? Quisiera que tenga el formato:

```
DD/MM/YYYY
```

Answer (score 1):

Al margen de los regex, hay una alternativa:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        string fecha = "31-12-2019";    
        var fechaValida = IsDateTime(fecha);
        Console.WriteLine(fechaValida); //Falso, explicación en el código de IsDateTime
        string fecha2 = "31/12/2019";
        var fechaValida2 = IsDateTime(fecha2);
        Console.WriteLine(fechaValida2); //Verdadero
    }

    public static bool IsDateTime(string fechaTemp)
    {
        DateTime fechaValidada;
        //Esto es la clave:
        var formatos = new[] { "MM/dd/yyyy", "dd/mm/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss" };
        //Para revisar todos los formatos soportados: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings
        return DateTime.TryParseExact(fechaTemp, formatos, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out fechaValidada);
    }
}
```

Es muy importante revisar la documentación:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 0):

Podría servir:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // string a probar
        string date = "31-12-2019";
        // iniciando un objeto de la clase Regex enviándole en el constructor la expresión regular 
        // para dd/mm/yyyy para años que empiecen en: 19xx a más
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|[2-9][0-9])\d\d$");   
        // guardando en el objecto de la clase Match el resultado de usar el método Match con el objeto
        // de la clase Regex enviándole como parámetro el string date
        Match m = regex.Match(date);
        // si el objeto de la clase Match tiene la fecha entonces será válida
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Value)) {
            Console.WriteLine(date + " is not valid");          
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine(date + " is valid");
        }       
    }
}
```